# The method startElement(String, String, String, Attributes) of type ... must override or implement a supertype method

Tags: java, android, sax

I use SAX Parser and when I add **@Override** to

```
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, 
        Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    //Do somethink :)
}
```

I have error:

> The method startElement(String, String, String, Attributes) of type ... must override or implement a supertype method

## UPDATE

Bottom I add full code of this file. If you want anythink else tell me :)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.util.Log;

public class ParseGEOLocal extends DefaultHandler {
 
    String tempLoc;
    private static ArrayList<Locations> locations;
    private Locations location;
 
    public ParseGEOLocal() {
        super();
        locations = new ArrayList<Locations>();
    }
    
    public static ArrayList<Locations> getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, 
            Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Result")){
            location = new Locations();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
            tempLoc = new String(ch, start, length);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Result"))
            locations.add(location);
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("city"))
            location.setCity(tempLoc);
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("uzip"))
            location.setUzip(tempLoc.replaceAll("[\\s\\-()]", ""));
        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("woeid"))
            location.setWOEID(tempLoc);
    }
 
}
```

Comment: show the class declaration.  what are you extending and implementing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import this...

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
```

instead of this...

```
import java.util.jar.Attributes;
```

Check that these are all match with your...

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class SSAXParserHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {

    }

}
```

Comment: `The import org.xml.sax.Attributes collides with another import statement`

Comment: yeah...I have seen it...and I have updated my answer...please, see it.